# coult not connect to server when running from docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a python code which connect to `postgres`:

```
import psycopg2
def start_connection(host, port, name, user, pass):
   connect = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, database=name, user=user, password=pass)
   return connect
```

when running the code from my development computer with same parameters, I can connect to postgres DB.

I built a docker of my application (which contains this code)

when I run the docker (`docker run my_docker:1`)
I'm getting error:

```
psycopg2.operationalError could not connect to server connection timeout
Is the server running on host "184.32.99.17" and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432 ?
```

Why I can connect when running from my developing computer and can't do so when running from docker ?
What do I need to fix it ?

Note:
I check and I have ping to the DB from the location the docker is running

Comment: Could you please describe where the postgres DB is running. I guess it's outside the container on a distant server maybe? Having all the information will help troubleshoot the problem. If it's the case you can try to `ping` the server `184.32.99.17` from within the container.

Comment: I have ping to the server